# Windows 10 thin scrollbars - but not in all apps?

Tags: css, windows, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

Windows 10 (April Release 1804) introduced "thin" scrollbars, similar to macOS. But it looks like they only apply to certain apps (like "Settings"), but not to "File Explorer", "Firefox" or "MS Edge".

1. Am I missing something? Are there really two kinds of scroll bars?
2. Is there any way to control that behavior with HTML/CSS/JS?

[image: Settings]

[image: Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

You could change the Scroll Bar Width to be Thinner by changing the Registry, please refer to the following steps:

1. Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe).
2. Navigate to the key below in the left pane of Registry Editor. (see screenshot below)

   ```
   Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics
   ```

   [image]
3. In the right panel of the **WindowsMetrics** key, double click the **ScrollWidth** string value to modify it. Enter a value between -120 (thinner) to -1500(thicker) for what you want, then click **OK** button to save the change.(screenshot as below)

   [image]
4. Double click the ScrollHeight key, and enter the value (between -120 (smaller) to -1500 (larger) for what you want), click the **OK** button to save the change.
5. Close the Registry Editor, restart the Computer.

Edit:

> Is there any way to control that behavior with HTML/CSS/JS?

I don't think we can modify it with HTML/CSS/JS, because it is the browser or windows behavior. If you want to change the html element's scrollbar with, you could use the [CSS scrollbar-width property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width).